# Reverse engineering proprietary magnetic card formats

Tags: encoding, reverse-engineering, magnetic-cards

I was playing around with a few magnetic cards (parking lot tickets, time limited access etc) with my MSR605 reader. 
When the format is ISO, it is quite straigforward to extract clear data. When it is not, I don't understand how I can decode the data on the card. I can't neither understand how I can see what kind of encoding has been used.

For example, I have one ticket printed out on the 17th of December 2016 @ 18:01:22. the raw data on the track 3 of the card is:

```
D58F6A9C21856A2AD6DE722A2AD6DE72021084210C2A1587DA591B6A849975AA70861525ABEB06A283841B78
```

I have another ticket printed out on the 17th of December 2016 @ 18:03:21. the raw data on the card is:

```
D58F6A9C21856A2AD5C1ACEA2AD5C1ACC21084210C2A1587DA779C8B0742ADAA70861525ABE779DC5B782778
```

You can find redundancies... But it is impossible for me to find where the complete date/time is!

More generally, how do you know  what kind of method is used to encoded data on a magnetic stripe?

Can you help me please to find the date/time on this magstripe and explain me how you did it?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a variety of different formats... a few standards but these aren't always followed.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the most common ones? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked on these card readers for the last 7 years.  I'm not the most knowledgeable on the topic.